# What is the most elegant way to transform both keys and values of an object using lodash?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

Say I have the following Object:

```
 var Models = { User: ... 
    { collection: 
         { name: 'users' }
     } ...
    , Post: { ...
    collection: 
     { name: 'posts'
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to turn this into:

```
 {'users': 'User', 'posts': 'Post'}
```

Does anyone have something more elegant than this approach (lodash):

```
    collectionNames = _.mapValues(_.mapKeys(Models, function(model) {
    return model.collection.name;
}), function(model) {
    return model.modelName;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with a basic loop, sort of easier to understand and no dependencies?

> node.js

```
var Models = { User: {collection: { name: 'users' }}, Post: { collection: {name:'posts' }}
var res = {}
for (var key in Models) res[Models[key].collection.name] = key
```

Comment: Yea, single line for loop is pretty elegant in this case.  Good answer, I'd like to see if there is a built in lodash method I haven't come across yet.  Thanks!

Comment: I wish JS had python-like map comprehensions or at least a `forEach` construct for such situations. Both would be more efficient and more elegant. But well, we work with what we get

Comment: I might be fully on `dart` by then :)